# How can I produce lists as the value in a dictionary key:value pair without producing loads of [[[['s

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a programme that reads a list of lists and produces a key from the first element in each list and a value from the other elements in the list. If the key already exists then the programme appends the list data to the existing value in the dictionary pair.

My code looks like:

```
# IMPORTS
from csv import reader

# VARIABLES

test_list = [['\ufeffCategory', 'materials', 'details', 'cost'], ['Clothes', 'Socks', 'Wool', '5'], ['Clothes', 'Shorts', 'Cotton', '5'], ['Clothes', 'Trousers', 'Cotton', '15'], ['Education', 'Books', 'Rymans', '10'], ['Education', 'Pens', 'Rymans', '12'], ['Education', 'Pencils', 'Rymans', '4'], ['Education', 'Paper', 'WH Smths', '3.5'], ['Education', 'computer', 'PC World', '800'], ['Entertainment', 'Kindle Unlimited', 'DD', '7.99'], ['Entertainment', 'Audible', 'On hold', '7'], ['Entertainment', 'Spotify', 'DD', '11.99'], ['Entertainment', 'Netflix', 'DD', '9']]

def make_dict_from_csv(test_list):
    """ read list make a key:value pair making the key the first element in list and the rest of the elements as the value"""
    budget_dict = {}
    i = 0
    starting_key = ""
    temp_list = []
    for item in test_list:
        key = test_list[i][0]
        if key != starting_key:
            value = [n for n in test_list[i][1:]]
            budget_dict[key] = value
            starting_key = key
            value = []
        else:
            value = []
            value = [n for n in test_list[i][1:]]
            temp_list = []
            for k, v in budget_dict.items():
                if k == starting_key:
                    temp_list = [v, value]
            budget_dict[key] = temp_list
            temp_list = []
        i += 1
    del budget_dict["\ufeffCategory"] # delete header data
    return budget_dict

budget_list = read_csv_make_list(file)
budget_dict = make_dict_from_csv(test_list)
print(budget_dict)
```

How can I 'flatten' the lists in the key:value pair so that I end up with e.g.

```
{'Clothes': [['Socks', 'Wool', '5'], ['Shorts', 'Cotton', '5'], ['Trousers', 'Cotton', '15']]}
```

rather than

```
{'Clothes': [[['Socks', 'Wool', '5'], ['Shorts', 'Cotton', '5']], ['Trousers', 'Cotton', '15']]}`
```

?

Comment: The nesting results from `temp_list = [v, value]`. It seems you are expecting this to take a single item `v` and a list `value`, and make a slightly longer list. It does not. It makes a list with exactly two elements - one which is `v`, and the other of which is `value`. Programming is very literal like that. Are you really not aware of any ways to prepend an element to a list? Did you try using a search engine to help? (Or maybe you just needed to know the word "prepend"?)

Comment: That said, there are *many* things in this code that don't make sense. Don't loop over a dictionary to search for a key; the **entire point** of using a dictionary is that you can just index in (`budget_dict[starting_key]`). Also, when you use `'\ufeffCategory'` as a key, do you actually know what the `'\xfeff'`  means? Do you know what Unicode is, and what a byte order mark is? Do you know how to specify file encoding?

Comment: I'm not sure why your code example says `import csv`,  because the code that you show isn't using it. But I **guess** that you created `test_list` by using the `csv` module earlier. I think what you *really* need to do here is **read the documentation for the `csv` module**. It has "build a dict from the data" as built-in functionality already. It does so *directly from the source file*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def make_dict_from_csv(test_list):
    budget_dict = dict()
    
    for sublist in test_list:
        key = sublist[0]
        if key=="\ufeffCategory":
            continue
        if key in budget_dict:
            budget_dict[key].append(sublist[1:])
        else:
            budget_dict[key] = [sublist[1:]]
    return budget_dict

>>> make_dict_from_csv(test_list)
{'Clothes': [['Socks', 'Wool', '5'], 
             ['Shorts', 'Cotton', '5'], 
             ['Trousers', 'Cotton', '15']],
 'Education': [['Books', 'Rymans', '10'], 
               ['Pens', 'Rymans', '12'], 
               ['Pencils', 'Rymans', '4'],
               ['Paper', 'WH Smths', '3.5'],
               ['computer', 'PC World', '800']],
 'Entertainment': [['Kindle Unlimited', 'DD', '7.99'],
                   ['Audible', 'On hold', '7'],
                   ['Spotify', 'DD', '11.99'],
                   ['Netflix', 'DD', '9']]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_dict_from_csv(test_list):
    ret = {}
    for i in range(1,len(test_list)):
        key = test_list[i][0]
        value = test_list[i][1:]
        if key not in ret:
            ret[key] = [value]
        else:
            ret[key].append(value)
    return ret
```

Comment: You can avoid checking the first row of the matrix by starting the for from 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can condense this greatly.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_dict_from_csv(test_list):

    itr = iter(test_list)
    next(itr)  # Skip the header
    budget_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for key, *value in itr:
        budget_dict[key].append(value)

    return budget_dict
```